# Spring OAuth2 social login integrated with NUXT 3

Tags: java, nuxt.js, spring-social, nuxt3

I am trying to implement Spring OAuth2 social login (i.e. google, github etc.) with database user persistence and roles.
The main challenge I'm facing is on the client-side integration with NUXT 3.
Despite extensive research through Google, YouTube, and GitHub, a clear guide or example eludes me.
I feel there's a straightforward solution for a fundamental requirement like this, but I'm stuck on the best approach to handle client-side implementation, particularly regarding token management post-redirect.
In my current setup with NUXT, I'm pondering whether to use Pinia for user and token management or to develop custom auth composables.
I've managed to extract the token from the URL (route.query.token), though I suspect there's a more appropriate method.

Thank you!

I've managed to extract the token from the URL (route.query.token), though I suspect there's a more appropriate method.